# Teamcenter PLMXML Delta Import - import new file into existing dataset

Tags: xml, import, delta, teamcenter

I'm trying to import an ExternalFile (ImanFile) into an existing dataset via plmxml "incremental import" (delta import) on Teamcenter 12.1.

Import does not raise any error/warning but there is a problem:

- The new ImanFile is created but NOT added to the dataset "References"

Also unexpected: you can find the newly created ImanFile using the UID, but NOT with the TC "ImanFile..." query

### PLM XML

```
<PLMXMLDelta xmlns="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema" schemaVersion="6" author="unset" time="" date="">
    <!-- the existing dataset in TC -->
    <ExternalReference type="DataSet" id="id6">
        <ApplicationRef application="Teamcenter" label="kTgRkZRHhy1RnD" version="kTgRkZRHhy1RnD"/>
    </ExternalReference>


    <Add id="id0">
        <!-- the new file -->
        <ExternalFile format="CATProduct" locationRef="add/test.CATProduct" id="id8"/>
    </Add>
    
    <Modify attributeName="memberRefs" targetRef="#id6" op="add" valueRefs="#id8"/>

</PLMXMLDelta>
```

### Log

---

```
   PLMXML Log File Header   
   ----------------------   
            IMPORT          
****************************
Server Hostname :  ...
Teamcenter version :  Teamcenter V12000.1...
Syslog-FileName :  ...
LOG-FileName is:  add.xml.log
XML-FileName is:  add.xml
XSLT-FileName is:  
TransferMode Name :  incremental_import
OverWrite-ExistingData is:  0
CheckOutObjects-UponExport is:  0
CheckFor-ExportPrivilege is:  1
****************************
****************************
XML Element ====>
Processed Element [ExternalReference] Id [#id6]
Imported As ====>
Processed Object [kTgRkZRHhy1RnD] of type [CATProduct]
Error: None
****************************
****************************
XML Element ====>
Processed Element [ExternalFile] Id [#id8]
Imported As ====>
Processed Object [H_hRkZRHhy1RnD] of type [ImanFile]
Error: None
****************************
=====  END OF (DETAILED OBJECT TRANSLATION) ===== 

///// Teamcenter Import Summary BEGIN: Processed the following PLMXML Elements
  Element:: ExternalFile                                       Count:: 1 
  Element:: ExternalReference                                  Count:: 1 
///// Teamcenter Import Summary: Processed the following Teamcenter Objects
 TCObject:: CATProduct                                         Count:: 1 
 TCObject:: ImanFile                                           Count:: 1 
///// Teamcenter Import Summary END: /////
```